# C# Directory not found

Tags: c#, filesystems

So my filesystem looks like this on absolute path:

> C:\Users\myname\source\repos\projectname\projectname\bin\Debug\data\orders

and I want to use relative path like this:

```
string path = "~/data/orders/" + sdat + ".txt";
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
{
writer.WriteLine(lines[0]);
writer.WriteLine(lines[1]);
writer.WriteLine(lines[2]);
}
```

but it gives the error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Nem található a következő elérési út egy része.: „C:\Users\myname\source\repos\projectname\projectname\bin\Debug\~\data\orders\2021.06.26.txt”.'

**Nem található a következő elérési út egy része** means **Path not found**

Comment: Relative paths are problematic, since they are relative to the _current directory_ (note this is _not necessarily_ the location of the EXE). And the current directory **is outside the control of your program**. What you _likely_ want to do is look relative to the folder that your EXE is contained in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
string path = "~/data/orders/" + sdat + ".txt";
```

to

```
string path = "data\\orders\\" + sdat + ".txt";
```

"~" is for url in asp.net not for local filesystem.

Comment: So if there is a '/' or a '\\' before the first folder, it uses absolute path, and when there isn't, it's relative. Thank you, that solved my problem, I'll accept as soon as I can. :D